# Shared queue and 2 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex, race-condition

I am using a queue shared between 2 threads in my program. One thread keeps pushing data to the queue, and second thread keeps popping data from the queue and writing to a vector.
My question is do I need condition variable along with mutex lock for this scenario when doing enqueue or dequeue operation? How to handle race condition ?

My code is as follows:

```
void push_data_to_queue(){
   mtx.lock();
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
   for( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            queue.push(i);
   }
}

void get_data_from_queue(){
       std::vector<int> v;
       mtx.lock();
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
          v.push_back(queue.front()));
          queue.pop();
       }
}

int main(){
   std::mutex mtx;
   std::thread(push_data_to_queue,std::ref(mtx));
   std::thread(get_data_from_queue,std::ref(mtx));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first point is you dont need to call mutex.lock() when you are using std::lock_guard.

second point is this senario there is only one writer thread and one reader thread there is no need for locking mechanism you can implement it with wait free approach or something like busy loop. but you can use just mutex but beware there is no guarantee that if reader or writer thread release mutex it will let other side acquire mutex in another word there is no guarantee ordering of acquisition because of that you need something like condition variable's(but beware condition variable also use for put thread in waiting state and prevent from wasting resources).

as i said you need some method of syncronazation.
imagine this senario:

```
writer thread write A to queue.

reader thread call back() and get item and start to process.

then writer thread write B to queue.

after that reader thread call pop_back() then it will remove item B from queue without processing.
```

so because of that you need mutex(no guarantee ordering of acquisition) , or condition variable(which is using mutex inside itself), busy loop(may consume so much resource), spinklock, ...

for better performance you can use atomic variable's.